# Parallel loop operating on/with class members

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to use openMP to parallelize some sections of a relatively complex simulation model of a car I have been programming in C++.

The whole model is comprised of several nested classes. Each instance of the class "Vehicle" has four instances of a class "Suspension", and each of them has one instance of the class Tyre. There's quite a bit more to it but it shouldn't be relevant to the problem.

I'm trying to parallelize the update of the Suspension on every integration step with a code that looks like follows. This code is part of another class containing other simuation data, including one or several cars.

```
for (int iCar = 0; iCar < this->numberOfCars; iCar++) { 
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1)
    for (int iSuspension = 0; iSuspension < 4; iSuspension++) { 
        this->cars[iCar].suspensions[iSuspension].update();
    }
}
```

I've actually simplified it a bit and changed the variable names hoping to make it a bit more understandable (and not being masking the problem by doning so!)

The method "update" just computes some data of the corresponding suspension on each time step and saves it in several proporties of its own instance of the Suspension class. All instances of the class Suspension are independent of each other, so that every call to the method "update" accesses only to data contained in the same instance of "Suspension".

The behaviour that I'm getting using the debugger can be described as follows:

- The first time the loop is run (at the first time step of the simulation) it runs ok. Always. All four suspensions are updated correctly.
- The second time the loop is run, or at the latest on the third, at least one of the suspensions become updated with correpted data. It's quite common that two of the suspension become exactly the same (corrupted) data, which shouldn't be possible, as they are configured from the start with slightly different parameters.
- If I run it with one loop instead of four (omp_set_num_threads(1)) it works flawlessly. Needless to say, the same applies when I run it without any openMP preprocessor directives.

I'm aware it may not be possible to figure out a solution to the problem without knowing how the rest of the program works, but I hope somebody can at least tell if there's any reason why you just can't access to properties and methods of a class within a parallel openMP loop the way I'm trying to do it.

I'm using W10 and Visual Studio 2017 Community. I tried to compile the project with and without optimizations, with no difference.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Probably something in `update` is not thread safe.  Unless what it is doing is computationally intense, the overhead of creating/using the threads will outweigh the time saved running multiple threads.

Comment: I assume, that on the first run openMP is starting the threads and therefore, the first loop is processed mostly sequentially, because the calculation of each update is already finished, when the next thread is started. On the second run, the 4 threads are already created and openMP can quickly distribute the tasks. That is the time when it comes to real parallel execution. But still this can only cause corruption, when the update() function is not thread safe.

Comment: Somehow your mention of update not beeing thread safe set me on the right path. A function being called by update contained a couple of static variables. Removing the static modifier made it work. Thanks a lot you two!